# Is there a badge for giving a highly up-voted recent answer to a very old question?

Tags: support

I have this theory that an answer today given to an old question is unlikely to be up-voted highly, if at all. I believe this is because people tend to lose interest in old questions, and can't be bothered to go through all the other answers to see if the new answer adds anything of value.

Is there some sort of badge for **giving a highly up-voted recent answer to a very old question** to check this?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you look for, but there are the [necromancer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/necromancer) and the [revival](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/revival) badges.

Comment: @Qmechanic Not quite, but not far off either so thanks. I was thinking more of an answer that is upvoted highly within a week , yet given to a question more than 1 year old say.

Comment: There isn't really something like that, but it might be worth proposing on [meta.se].

Comment: You might be interested in my post on [Age-Score relation](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6645/).